# adding inline styling on appended items on run time having issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have an "`a`" tag into a "`li`" and am appending few images on hover of a "`li`" into same "a" tag and I have to use inline style on all those img elements but the problem is when I hover first time on "li" these styles apply only on first img tag which is always exist there but not on others but if I hover over "`li`" again then those inline styles applies on all img tags. for this am using this JS code given below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var mouseover_interval;
var $image;

$('li.product-details').mouseenter(function() {
current_image = -1;
$image = $(this).find('a.current_product_image img');
data_srcs = $image.attr('data-srcs').split(",");

if(data_srcs.length >1){
  for (var i = data_srcs.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    img = new Image ;
    img.src = data_srcs[i];
    new_img = $('<img>').attr('src', data_srcs[i]).css({display:"none"}).addClass("over");
    $(this).find('a.current_product_image').append(new_img);
    var countImg = $(this).find('a.current_product_image img');
    countImg.each(function(){
      $(this).css({
        position : 'absolute',
        left : '50%',
        marginLeft : -$(this).width()/2,
        top : '50%',
        marginTop : -$(this).height()/2,
      });
    });
  }
}
else{
  return false;
}

$images = $(this).find('a.current_product_image img.over');
mouseover_interval = setInterval(function(){
{
    $image.fadeOut(500);
    if(current_image == -1){
      $($images[$images.length-1]).fadeOut(500);
    }
    else{
      $($images[current_image]).fadeOut(500);  
    }

    current_image+=1; 
    $($images[current_image]).fadeIn(500);

    if(current_image == $images.length-1){
      current_image = -1;
    }
  }
}, 1000);
}).mouseleave( function(){
clearInterval(mouseover_interval);
$image.fadeIn(500);
$(this).find('a.current_product_image img.over').remove();
});
});
```

How to add styles on all appended elements hovering over "`li`" first time? Please let me know if am using anything wrong there.

Thanks in advance,
Ashwani Sharma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this is happening is - most likely - the additional images haven't loaded into the DOM yet (remember that it takes time for assets - particularly images - to load when you add them in dynamically).

To confirm this, try logging the `countImg` var and see whether it reports one too few for the number of images you expect to have.  I suspect that's your issue.

You could try passing attributes into the element before adding it into the page.  Something like this:

```
new_img = $('<img>', {
    src: data_srcs[i],
    class: 'over'
}).hide();
```

This should create an object that looks like:

```
<img src="your/source.jpg" class="over" style="display: none;" />
```

Your problem will still be that it won't actually load into the page until you turn off the `display: none`, most browsers are intelligent enough to not pull images until they are actually needed (ie: not when hidden).

Also note that your declaration of `$image` is only set once, at the very beginning of the function.  It therefore will only contain the elements it finds *at that point in time*.  If you dynamically add additional images (ie: your `new_img`)to the parent element, they won't automatically get added to that `$image` variable.

Comment: right John this is the same issue, images are loading late into the DOM. I just tried logging the countImg and on hovering first time its just loading images without styles. So is there any to pre-add styles on appended items?